# Problems with including antlr4 in an angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio, antlr, antlr4

actually I have a problem with incuding an antlr4 grammar in my angular project written in visual studio code. I could create the grammar itself (the .g4 file) and there was automatically built an .antlr folder, in which are the following files:

[image]

However, these are only the java files and I need for the browser the javascript version. At this point I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: What did you use to generate these files? If it was the `vscode-antlr4` extension then set the target language in its preferences. See in particular the [language](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/doc/extension-settings.md#parser-generation) settings.

Comment: @Mike Lischke Yes I used this extension and solved the problem via the settings, because the terminal didn't function. However, now I run into the problem that an error occurs: "ERROR in ./node_modules/antlr4/FileStreams.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ...". I found out that fs is no longer available in angular 6+. Unfortunetly I found no possibility to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, VS Code automatically does something like this behind the scenes:

```
java -cp antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool Grammar.g4
```

which generates the default target language (Java).

To let it generate Javascript sources, do something like this from your terminal where your grammar is located:

```
java -cp antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool -Dlanguage=JavaScript Grammar.g4
```

Assuming you have `antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar` in the same folder as your `Grammar.g4` file.

You should be able to change this settting in [`antl4.generation -> language=JavaScript`](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/doc/extension-settings.md#parser-generation)

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me quite a lot:)